# Converting list of data frames to a data table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a list of data frames eg:

```
listOfDataFrames <- vector("list", 10)

for (i in 1:10) {
    listOfDataFrames[[i]] <- data.frame(a=rnorm(50), b=rnorm(50))
}
```

I want to make a single data table with 3 columns (a,b,c) where a and b are the columns of the data frames above and c is the index of the data frame in listOfDataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just do something like the following:

```
library(data.table)
Lens <- vapply(listOfDataframes, nrow, 1L)
rbindlist(listOfDataframes)[, c := rep(seq_along(Lens), times = Lens)][]
#               a          b  c
#   1: -1.6462894  1.0232899  1
#   2: -0.5145108 -0.2134384  1
#   3: -0.1171853  2.5456709  1
#   4:  0.2735289  1.1948928  1
#   5:  0.5739892  0.3939964  1
#  ---                         
# 496:  0.9539835 -1.4100199 10
# 497: -0.8697604  0.6793800 10
# 498:  0.8601795 -0.3015890 10
# 499:  0.8306091 -2.2269960 10
# 500: -1.3407596  0.5014448 10
```

Basically, "Lens" just figures out how many rows there are in each list item (in this case, 50 in each), and then you just use `rep` to calculate the value for column "c". Since the result of `rbindlist` is a `data.table`, you can just use `:=` to assign the value of "c" in a compound statement.

---

With the [**development version**](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) you can now replace the `vapply` part with the new `idcol` argument. `idcol` is always of *character* type.

```
rbindlist(listOfDataframes, idcol = "c")
```

Comment: Great answer. What is the purpose of 1L in vapply?

Comment: @codeln, when you use `vapply` (as opposed to, say, `sapply`) you need to provide a "template" that specifies the output format expected. In this case, the output for `nrow` is a single integer, so we specify that as "1L".

Comment: You could also just do it in one line such as `rbindlist(Map(cbind, listOfDataframes, c = seq_len(length(listOfDataframes))))` though not sure about efficiency.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I would *guess* that your suggestion would be far less efficient since you actually have to create a bunch of new `data.frame`s with three columns instead of two whereas `rep` (and `nrow`) are pretty efficient.

Comment: Is there a function like rbindlist that works on list of lists?

Comment: something like:
listOfList <-NULL
for i in 1:10{
    listOfList[[i]] <- 1:10 
}

Comment: @codeln, what output do you want with that? A two-column `data.frame`? David's answer would work with that case too, and this one would require very slight modification.

Comment: yes, the output I am expecting is a two column data.table

Comment: @codeln, something like this should work (in addition to David's answer): `Len <- vapply(listOfLists, length, 1L); data.table(a = unlist(listOfLists, use.names = FALSE), b = rep(seq_along(Len), times = Len))`.

Comment: I would like to know how to turn the list into data table when each element of the list have different header or col-names ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't want to ruin the `data.table` party, but with `tidyr` it would a one liner, though you will get an additional `X` in the column index which you can later remove (if you wish) using `gsub` as follows:

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
setDT(unnest(listOfDataframes, "c"))[, c := gsub("X", "", c)][]
#       c          a          b
#   1:  1  0.3852528 -0.6886418
#   2:  1 -2.3344659 -1.6770465
#   3:  1 -0.8241178 -0.1445429
#   4:  1 -1.5560673 -1.4205030
#   5:  1  0.5981992  0.3564583
# ---                         
# 496: 10  0.1460643  1.1055989
# 497: 10  0.3094036 -0.4239363
# 498: 10  0.7756495  0.7656453
# 499: 10  1.0037946 -0.2417804
# 500: 10 -0.1241405  3.2421323
```

You can also reorder the columns by reference if you want (if you saved this object lets say in `Res`), using `setcolorder` function

```
setcolorder(Res, c(2, 3, 1))
```

Comment: How is this working? `?unnest` says `col` - Name of the column that needs to be unnested. But `"c"` doesn't exist.